# Reading h264 or h265 stream with ffmpeg/OpenCV: Which is faster?

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg, h.264

I'm using OpenCV with ffmpeg support to read a RTSP stream coming from an IP camera and then to write the frames to a video. The problem is that the frame size is 2816x2816 at 20 fps i.e. there's a lot of data coming in.

I noticed that there was a significant delay in the stream, so I set the buffer size of the `cv::VideoCapture` object to 1, because I thought that the frames might just get stuck in the buffer instead of being grabbed and processed. This however just caused for frames to be dropped instead.

My next move was to experiment a bit with the frame size/fps and the encoding of the video that I'm writing. All of those things helped to improve the situation, but in the long run I still have to use a frame size of 2816x2816 and support up to 20 fps, so I can't set it lower sadly.

That's where my question comes in: given the fact that the camera stream is going to be either h264 or h265, which one would be read faster by the `cv::VideoCapture` object? And how should I encode the video I'm writing in order to minimize the time spent decoding/encoding frames?

That's the code I'm using for reference:

```
using namespace cv;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    VideoCapture cap;
    cap.set(CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE, 1); // internal buffer will now store only 1 frames

    if (!cap.open("rtsp://admin:admin@1.1.1.1:554/stream")) {
        return -1;
    }
    VideoWriter videoWr;
    Mat frame;
    cap >> frame;
    //int x264 = cv::VideoWriter::fourcc('x', '2', '6', '4'); //I was trying different options
    int x264 = cv::VideoWriter::fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G');
    videoWr = cv::VideoWriter("test_video.avi", 0, 0, 20, frame.size(), true);

    namedWindow("test", WINDOW_NORMAL);
    cv::resizeWindow("test", 1024, 768);
    
    for (;;)
    {
        cap >> frame;
        if (frame.empty()) break; // end of video stream
        
        imshow("test", frame);
        if (waitKey(10) == 27) break; 
        videoWr << frame;
        
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Anything preventing you from running some benchmarks yourself, on your own hardware and software?

Comment: If I face problems with latency, I use the `cv2.VideoCapture` object with the gstreamer backend.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Nothing is preventing me, I just don't have a lot of experience when it comes to encoding/decoding so I was wondering if there's some piece of theory that I'm missing. What kind of benchmark would you suggest by the way?

Comment: @mibrahimy So the gstreamer backend should run faster than ffmpeg? I was looking at this option earlier as well, but I was unsure if it's going to make any difference.

Comment: You should experience close to no latency with gstreamer backend.

Comment: What's the hardware you are decoding on?

Comment: @mibrahimy I'm using a 64 bit windows machine with an Intel Cor i7-7600U 2C@2.8 GHz processor. I'm pretty sure there is no dedicated GPU since it's an embedded system. What generally worries me is that I had these problems without running anything else on it and in reality I will also have a couple of other application doing some extra processing. Thank you for the answers though.

Comment: Did you try the gstreamer?

Comment: @mibrahimy sadly not yet, I just built the library, but I probably won't have enough time today. I will post again as soon as I manage to test it. Thank you for your efforts, I appreciate it.